# Managing Multiple Branches in one project intellij

Tags: svn, configuration, intellij-idea

Where I currently work we have a new branch of svn for each release cycle, so I need to work on multiple branches of the same project. This has caused me problems because sometimes I edit the file in the wrong branch and commit against the wrong branch which I want to avoid.

Currently I create a new module for each branch and remove the other module branch from the project to avoid the above problem. Can I avoid having to delete and add the module when I switch branches.

I have tried:
Using contexts - I saved a context, swapped the module then saved another context but when I switch between the contexts they are the same it doesn't switch the module.

A nice solution would be to put each module on a sparate changelist

Comment: You can try solution described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296930/workflow-for-multiple-svn-branches-in-intellij-idea/10297121#10297121

Comment: I have asked this question on the jetbrains forums http://devnet.jetbrains.net/thread/440153?tstart=0, having separate projects as suggested in that question isn't really any better than changing the module IMO

Answer (score 0):

Consider

- having separate IntelliJ project per branch (like already mentioned in [Workflow for multiple SVN branches in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296930/workflow-for-multiple-svn-branches-in-intellij-idea/10297121#10297121))
- svn switch command to point to different branches from your workspace depending on the version your currently working with
  http://ldc.usb.ve/docs/svn/svn.branchmerge.switchwc.html

Also, work with patches/shelves to reuse local configuration.

Hope this helps!